# What is the easiest way to get the "Midnight Launch" achievement?

Tags: achievements, halo-4

I've been Halo achievement hunting, and I realized the hardest one will be Midnight Launch. I've been searching and there are many methods, but what's the best way to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to change your system clock. To do that, you need to be offline, and then just go to your settings. During the mission, there is a section near the beginning where you go off of a jump that should net you the achievement fairly easily. All detailed in the guide below.

Comment: doesn't it have to be on  specific date too? or am I mixing that up with Arkham City's Calendar Man achievement?

Comment: @Ben No, no specific date required.

Comment: ok so I was confusing the two... Haha that Calendar Man cheev was so annoying! This is nothing compared to that. You had to go and talk to Calendar Man on every (American) holiday, which went off the system calendar.